# How to extract coefficients in "cv.rq.pen" function in R?

Tags: r, model, cross-validation

```
library(rqPen)
n <- 60
p <- 7
rho <- .5
beta <- c(3,1.5,0,2,0,0,0)
R <- matrix(0,p,p)
for(i in 1:p){
  for(j in 1:p){
    R[i,j] <- rho^abs(i-j)
  }
}
set.seed(1234)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p) %*% t(chol(R))
y <- x %*% beta + rnorm(n)
q.lasso_scad = cv.rq.pen(x, y, tau = 0.5, lambda = NULL, penalty = "SCAD", intercept = FALSE, criteria = "CV", cvFunc = "check", nfolds = 10,
                         foldid = NULL, nlambda = 100, eps = 1e-04, init.lambda = 1,alg="QICD")

q.lasso_scad

coef1 = q.lasso_scad$models[[which.min(q.lasso_scad$cv[,2])]]
coef1
```

I have the following output

```
Coefficients:
        x1         x2         x3         x4         x5         x6         x7         x8         x9        x10 
 0.0000000  0.3226967  1.8131688 -0.1971847  0.1981571  0.7715635 -0.2289284 -0.1087028  0.9713283 -0.1079333
```

I want to extract the coefficients only. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: broom https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html?

Comment: In addition, your code as an error: Error in cv.rq.pen(x, y, tau = 0.5, lambda = NULL, penalty = "SCAD", intercept = FALSE,  : 
  CV criteria not implemented for QICD algorithm with nonconvex penalties. Please use BIC or PBIC instead. Changing it to "BIC" also results with error

Comment: @DJV Thank you. I just figure out `coef1 = q.lasso_scad$models[[which.min(q.lasso_scad$cv[,2])]]`. But I want to extract only the coefficients.

Comment: please edit your question so we'll be able to help you and reproduce the same dataset :)

Comment: q.lasso_scad is not defined in your script...

Comment: @DJV the `tidy` function in `broom` package didn't work. It say `Error: No tidy method for objects of class rq.pen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit backwards but you can do:

```
as.data.frame(as.list.data.frame(coef1)$coefficients)
```

Result:

```
  as.list.data.frame(coef1)$coefficients
x1                             3.17487201
x2                             1.15712559
x3                             0.05078333
x4                             2.27113756
x5                             0.24893740
x6                             0.00000000
x7                            -0.07542964
```

If I understand the issue correctly, the output from `rqPen` is some sort of a fancy `list` with additional attributes. `as.list.data.frame` basically forces `coef1` to be a "normal" list, which allows me to use `$coefficients` to extract the coefficients values. Lastly, I use `as.data.frame` to convert it into a more usable object.

If you just want the values, you can replace `as.data.frame` with `as.vector`:

```
as.vector(as.list.data.frame(coef1)$coefficients)
```

Result:

```
[1]  3.17487201  1.15712559  0.05078333  2.27113756  0.24893740  0.00000000
[7] -0.07542964
```

Comment: How to separate the coefficients column only? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I want to have to have the coefficients column `c(0.0000000  0.3226967  1.8131688 -0.1971847  0.1981571  0.7715635 -0.2289284 -0.1087028  0.9713283 -0.1079333)`. Because, I need to do matrix multiplication.

Comment: You can also replace `as.vector` with `as.matrix`, if matrix is what you're looking for. You're most welcome and glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider to upvote or accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to R program, so I can't verify that it will work. But try this:

```
names(coef1) <- NULL
coef1
```

Comment: How about ``unname(coef1)``?

Comment: Its again return the same output.